# How quickly do gecko skins deteriorate?

Tags: biology

I mean the skin that a gecko would shed when molting. I have a group of people in my story that collect them, but I'm not sure how well they would keep. Couldn't find anything on Google, but I may just not know where to look. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could we have a bit more context? What technology does the group have access to? How do they *want* to store them?

Comment: Hi, as questions about facts about the real world are off topic on Worldbuilding, unless this question is made more specific in terms of showing that your group of people has some future technology or perhaps if you edit the question to ask the best way to keep the skins or something, I think that this question would be better served on the likes of the [Biology SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: parchment is skin,  it lasts thousands of years if kept dry and away from things that would eat it,.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Biology SE. https://biology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Real world questions are only on topic if the aim is to build a fictional world based on the answer. I can't see how this question meets this criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen snake skins in museums that must have been 100 years old.  I would not think gecko skins would be that different.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggested method for preserving snake skins. Assume gecko skins will no different.

> It is relatively easy to preserve shed skins, but tanning the skin of a deceased snake requires special chemicals and techniques. Preserving a shed skin takes a matter of minutes, but the tanning process will take several days.
>
> Preserve Shed Skins
>
> Try to remove the shed skin from your snake’s cage as soon as
>   possible; the sooner you remove the skin from the cage, the easier it
>   will be to straighten any folded or inverted portions, as the skin
>   will still be moist. Gently straighten the skin and stretch it out to
>   air dry. You can hang the skin or place it flat on a piece of
>   cardboard to facilitate the drying process, which should take only a
>   few days.
>
> Once the skin is dry, glue it on some type of mounting board. Place a
>   thin piece of glass on top of the skin to protect it. Alternatively,
>   place the shed skin in a plastic envelope and pass it through a
>   thermal laminating machine. This will seal the skin in plastic and
>   protect it from wear and tear.

Source: [Preserving shed snake skin](https://www.cuteness.com/article/preserve-shed-snake-skin)

This may answer your question. There is some uncertainty about whether you want preserve them as exhibits or souvenirs or for some other undisclosed purpose.

This information was found by googling "lizard skin preservation". other possible sources might be found by searching 'reptile skins", plus "care" or "preservation". Look for recurring terms in articles or websites related to this and similar subjects.